# Ferrite bead pi-filter vs feed through capacitors in supply decoupling

Tags: decoupling, filtering

How do I choose a feed through (feedthrough/feed-through?) capacitor to replace a ferrite bead pi-filter circuit? Manufacturers quote capacitance figures but what value should I choose this to be?

The reference design of a CPU design filters out, from a common VDD, various filtered power inputs (several pins per input). Per input, a pi-filter is given plus 100nF per pin. I have read good things about the feed through capacitors and want to replace the pi-filter with one. I am unclear what value of capacitance should be chosen though.

Filter is currently Power->1uF cap->120R@100M FB-> 10uF cap

1uF 0201 caps will be used per pin.

Answer (score 1):

All filters are voltage-dividers, having a SERIES reactance followed by a SHUNT reactance. What are your needs for these two reactances? Define those needs first.

The preceding components, and the components that follow your filter, must be considered.

And **WIRES** are part of the SERIES reactances. At 1uH per meter, if not part of twisted-pair or coax or over ground/power plane or metal chassis.